# Jackson Mixin Deserializer not calling Setter

Tags: java, spring, jackson, mixins

I have a POJO class & Mixin like below.

When calling Jackson I expect `{'enquiry_id':'1234'}` to work but the setter method is not called and the getter returns `null`. When I pass it in input as `{'enquiryId':'1234'}` it gets deserialized correctly.

Before using Mixin, I was using the same annotation directly in the class and was not facing this problem.

```
public class Party {
  private String enquiryId;
  public String getEnquiryId() {
    return enquiryId;
  }

  public String setEnquiryId(String enquiryId) {
    this.enquiryId = enquiryId;
  }
}
```

```
public abstract class PartyMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("enquiry_id") String enquiryId;
}
```

Can anybody elaborate why the Jackson Mixin Deserializer is not calling the `setEnquiryId(String enquiryId)` method of Party Class.

Example usage

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotation.Api;
@Api(value = "Party Api")
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @ApiOperation(value = "Process Party", notes = "Example usage {'enquiry_id':'1234'}")
    @RequestMapping(value = "process", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Party process(@RequestBody Party party) throws IOException, HttpException {
        // Here i get party.getEnquiryId() as null
        return party;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableCaching
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> mc : converters) {
             if (mc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter || mc instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
                ((AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) mc).getObjectMapper().addMixIn(Party.class, PartyMixIn.class);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show all imports and example usage?

Comment: It works fine. I tried in my local, and after fixing some compilation errors that I suppose come from copying to the question, it parses it as expected. The problem should be somewhere else. Also, that JSON you are passing is incorrect